# faultCode argument for createFault was passed NULL

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsimport

I have generated the WSDL proxies using WSImport tool.

Now, when I call the webservice method using the generated port, I get the following exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: faultCode argument for createFault was passed NULL
```

Have anybody ever noticed this exception, because I couldn't find any other question on SO with this exception.

> SOAP Response

```
<soapenv:Fault>
   <soapenv:faultcode>soap:Client</soapenv:faultcode>
   <soapenv:faultstring>Given name with Parent ID is existing.Hence same cant be used again - Trans : TransName</soapenv:faultstring>
   <soapenv:detail>
      <NS1:Error xmlns:NS1="http://com.example.com/schemas/XYZ_error">
         <Error_type_code>11</Error_type_code>
         <Error_Type>Database Error</Error_Type>
         <Error_code/>
         <Error_text>Given name with Parent ID is existing.Hence same cant be used again</Error_text>
         <Backend_applid/>
         <Payload><![CDATA[]]></Payload>
      </NS1:Error>
   </soapenv:detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

Comment: This exception is telling you're passing a null value to createFault, need more info for try to help you.

Comment: Please find the soap response, it has faultCode

Comment: did you make any progress on this? I just ran into this same exception today.

Comment: @csturtz See my answer below..

Answer (score 1):

The issue is resolved

This occurred because of an contract mismatch, meaning the response XML sent by the web service was not matching the contract created by the WSDL.

In order to fix this, check whether the response XML you receive has the same namespace as that of contract created by Java code and also the response XML elements match the properties in Java code.

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074099/faultcode-argument-for-createfault-was-passed-null-with-metro-2-3 wich is a very similar error. In this case, the error was due to Fault child elements: no namespace are expected for faultcode, faultstring and detail.